# TimeSynchronizer Callback problem

Tags: ros, timesynchronizer, approximatetime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem using the TimeSynchronizer.

I added sub1 and sub2 to test if there is a with the subscriber, but in both cases the callbacks test_callback and test_callback2 are called.
Only the synchronized callback is not called.

Thank you very much.

Here is the main part:

```
ros::Subscriber sub1 = nh.subscribe("/camera/rgb/image_rect_color", 1, test_callback);
ros::Subscriber sub2 = nh.subscribe("/camera/depth_registered/image_rect", 1, test_callback2);
    
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> image_sub(nh, "/camera/rgb/image_rect_color", 1);
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> depth_sub(nh, "/camera/depth_registered/image_rect", 1);
    
TimeSynchronizer<sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::Image> sync(image_sub, depth_sub, 10);
sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60903/timesynchronizer-callback-problem/) by [Waterplant](https://answers.ros.org/users/4689/waterplant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The TimeSynchronizer will only work when the timestamps are exactly equal. You need to use the ApproximateTimeSyncronizer:
Example (copied from rgbdslam):

```
typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image, 
                                                        sensor_msgs::Image,
                                                        sensor_msgs::CameraInfo> NoCloudSyncPolicy;

class MyClass {
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> *visua_sub_;      
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> *depth_sub_;      
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo> *cinfo_sub_;      
message_filters::Synchronizer<NoCloudSyncPolicy>* no_cloud_sync_;

// method definitions needed here
}

void MyClass::init()
{
std::string visua_tpc("/topic_image_mono");
std::string depth_tpc("/topic_image_depth");
std::string cinfo_tpc("/camera_info_topic");
int q = 5; //queue size
ros::NodeHandle nh;

visua_sub_ = new image_sub_type(nh, visua_tpc, q);
depth_sub_ = new image_sub_type(nh, depth_tpc, q);
cinfo_sub_ = new cinfo_sub_type(nh, cinfo_tpc, q);

no_cloud_sync_ = new message_filters::Synchronizer<NoCloudSyncPolicy>(NoCloudSyncPolicy(q),  *visua_sub_, *depth_sub_, *cinfo_sub_);

no_cloud_sync_->registerCallback(boost::bind(&MyClass::callbackMethod, this, _1, _2, _3));
}

//The callback method
void MyClass::callbackMethod (const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& visual_img_msg,
                              const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& depth_img_msg,
                              const sensor_msgs::CameraInfoConstPtr& cam_info_msg) 
{
     //Your processing code
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Waterplant](https://answers.ros.org/users/4689/waterplant/) on 2013-04-18**:
Thank you very much.
That sounds logic

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2016-06-28**:
I found this helpful, but linking to original source would be even more helpful as the typedefs for image_sub_type and cinfo_sub_type are missing (https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/blob/5a4c439b0b89e25ac96c03b74cba397187ea9dda/src/openni_listener.cpp#L55).